# Error in SQL script file

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a database and we are trying to make a script file that will give us the total number of orders in july.

How exactly would I say july because I know syntax is wrong and I would be using sum instead of count right?

Please help, This is what I tried

```
 use Cis11101_Northwind
 Declare @Julycount int
 Set @Julycount= (Select sum(*) From orders Where OrderDate = 'july')
 print 'The total orders for july is ' + Cast(@JulyCount as varchar)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can USE [MONTH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187813.aspx) to get month from the Date. if you want to match with July then `MONTH(date) = 7`

```
(Select sum(*) From orders Where MONTH(OrderDate) = 7)
```

OR

You can use [DateName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx)

```
  (Select sum(*) From orders Where datename(month, OrderDate) = 'July')
```